# How to insert strings with pipe symbol in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 but I am encountering some problems as I need to add strings containing the `|` symbol

I have a table with just one column, and i do this:

```
s.execute('INSERT INTO mytable (col_name) VALUES (?);',"a|b")
```

But as a result i get this:

```
ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.
```

I've also tried quoting, like this:

```
s.execute('INSERT INTO mytable (col_name) VALUES (?);',"'a|b'")
```

And the error is kind of different but still doesn't work

```
ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied.
```

How can I convince sqlite3 to accept my string as a single string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter argument must be a sequence, so use a tuple here:

```
s.execute('INSERT INTO mytable (col_name) VALUES (?);', ("a|b",))
```

This has nothing to do with the pipe symbol, btw, but everything with the fact that strings are sequences too. A string of 3 characters is a sequence of 3 elements.